Wavelets vs Windowed Fourier
Are there any good simple examples where wavelet scalograms provide more information than windowed fourier?
P.s It would be even cooler if there was an example of what cannot be obtained from a spectrogram, but can be obtained from a scalogram.

"More information" is probably not the right term. Both are orthobasis expansions, so both are information preserving. The main thing that wavelets retain that a Fourier transform doesn't is time localization. Over whatever interval you compute the Fourier transform, you have no time localization, whereas you retain some time localization with wavelets.

Both transformations contain the same amount of information from the signal. But the choice of the representation makes some type of information more easily available (and other less).
What are these types of information? They are the localization characteristics of your features of interest, which should be resolved by the resolution of the chosen time-frequency or time-scale representation.
For the short-time / windowed Fourier (or Gabor) transform, with window duration $\tau$, you have two variables $(t,f)$ and associated uncertainty principle fixing the time-frequency resolutions: $\Delta t=\tau$ and $\Delta f = \tau^{-1}$ so that your atom of time-frequency uncertainty (the resolution) can be represented by the square $(\Delta t,\Delta f)$.
For the wavelet transform, the shift and scale variables $(b,a)$ are analogous to time and frequency $(t=b, f=f_\psi/a)$ for some wavelet-dependent frequency $f_\psi$ for the conversion. The wavelet as no fixed duration but a fixed number of oscillation $f\Delta t = Q$. We call $Q$ the quality factor of the wavelet, which also represents the inverse of the relative bandwidth $\frac{\Delta f}{|f|}=Q^{-1}$. Your atom of time-frequency uncertainty thus has a different shape $(|f|\Delta t,|f|^{-1}\Delta f)$.
Take these equations with a pinch of salt, since there are so many ways of defining a "number of oscillation", a "duration", a "bandwidth", a "quality factor". You would have to define them carefully for these equations to hold. But they capture the good order of magnitude in general.
What does this all mean in practice? When you look for a feature 1 in your signal, it has some characteristics, like its position $(t_1,f_1)$ and some width or localization $(\Delta t_1,\Delta f_1)$. In order to resolve correctly this feature, you need to choose:

either a window with duration $\tau$ satisfying:
$$(\Delta f_1)^{-1}<\tau<\Delta t_1$$

or a wavelet with quality factor  satisfying:
$$\frac{|f|}{\Delta f_1}<Q<f_1\Delta t_1$$


This is always doable according to the Heisenberg uncertainty principle, that we could write here as follows:
$$\Delta t_1 \Delta f_1 = (|f_1|\Delta t_1)(|f_1|^{-1} \Delta f_1) \geq 1 \quad .$$
Now assume there is another feature 2 that you would like to resolve in the same representation. And a feature 3, and 4, etc. You see that you certainly won't be able to resolve them all (satisfy the above condition)  in the same representation (with the same $\tau$ or the same $Q$).
In some cases, a representation with constant scale $\tau$ would achieve it best (there is a typical scale for most of your features that separates frequencies from durations), in some other cases a constant-$Q$ representation will work better (your features are at very different scales but all rather oscillatory/narrowband or all rather impulsive/wideband for instance).
In other cases we may need non-standard representations (say with $\tau(t)$ or $Q(f)$ not constant), and sometimes no single representation is sufficient since you may have features at the same position $(t_1,f_1)=(t_2,f_2)$ in the time-frequency plane, but with very different localization (for instance $\Delta t_1\gg\Delta t_2$ and $\Delta f_1\ll \Delta f_2$).

welcome to DSP.SE.
